# Constructing a Banach space between H1 and H2

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am not 100% sure how to phrase this question, since I am not an expert on the topic. But, here's my best attempt: I am interested in constructing a Banach space $E(\Omega)$, where $H^2(\Omega) \subset E(\Omega) \subset H^{1}(\Omega)$. Perhaps the most natural way to do this, is to define a new norm:

\begin{align}
\left\| f \right\|_{E(\Omega)}^{2} = \left\| f \right\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}^{2} + \Phi(f),
\end{align}

where $\Phi(f)$ is a suitable seminorm. Obviously, we recover $H^{2}(\Omega)$ if

\begin{align}
\Phi(f) = \left|f \right|_{H^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}.
\end{align}

Therefore, for well-known seminorms, this is a relatively straightforward exercise. However, I would like to know if $E(\Omega)$ is still a Banach space when
\begin{align}
\Phi(f) = \left| \int_{\Omega} \nabla^{2}f \, dx \right|,
\end{align}
i.e. when $\Phi(f)$ is a very weak seminorm? If the answer is no, then can I do this with a slightly stronger seminorm

\begin{align}
\Phi(f) = \int_{\Omega} \left| \nabla^{2}f \right| \, dx.
\end{align}

Any insight you can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more a remark then an answer, note that the mentioned Sobolev spaces can be represented by means of the Fourier transform $\mathscr F$. We have for integer $k \ge 0$:
$$ H^k(\mathbf R^d) = \{f \in L^2(\mathbf R^d): \mathscr (1 + |\cdot|^2)^{k/2}\mathscr Ff \in L^2(\mathbf R^d)\} $$
This generalises to a non-integer $s \ge 0$ quite easily:
$$ H^s(\mathbf R^d) := \{f \in L^2(\mathbf R^d): \mathscr (1 + |\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathscr Ff \in L^2(\mathbf R^d)\} $$
with the norm
$$ \|f\|_s := \|(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathscr Ff\|_{L^2}. $$
Note - as Fourier is a global operation - we must work on $\mathbf R^d$, but can restrict ourselves afterwards, we can define:
$$ H^s(\Omega) := \{f \in L^2(\Omega): \exists g \in H^s(\mathbf R^d): g|_\Omega = f \} $$
with
$$\|f\|_{s,\Omega} := \inf_{g \in H^s(\mathbf R^d), g|_\Omega = f} \|g\|_{s}. $$
Now, for example $H^{3/2}(\Omega)$ is an intermediate space between $H^1$ and $H^2$.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I'm familiar with $H^{3/2}(\Omega)$, but I am looking for something that is constructed based on a seminorm. Basically, I want to build an intermediate space between H1 and H2 by adding something to the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm. Any suggestions on how to do this?